# Using 'grep' and the output of `grep` as variable in second command to get user Id of folders

Tags: grep, disk-usage

I am using the following commandd to get the % of disk used `df -h| grep workfld`, than getting the top folders that are using the most disk space in %, the last piece would be to use the output/result from `du -h /saswork | sort -rh | head -20` in the final `grep` command to get the `USERID` of the user who's folder this is. To make code readable here it is broke into steps

```
df -h| grep saswork
du -h /saswork | sort -rh | head -20
ls -la|  grep %OUTPUT_FROM_COMMAND_2%
```

Whats the proper/easiest way to do this so I can do this repeatedly for say the top 5 folders and get the userIDs of those folders?

so results from second command would look something like this: 
569G/saswork/SAS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03/SAS_work9A0700007078_prdsasgridn03
569G/saswork/**SAS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03**

There would be the top 20 results though. The piece I want to use as input in the 3rd command would be the folder name in bold above is what I would need to go into the third command, so the third command would look like this:

```
ls -la|  grep SAS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03
```

This commands output will give me the userID. I want to run this for each foldername that is produced from the output of the second command that is run.

**Adding for more exact example**

```
Input: df -h| grep saswork
Output: /dev/mapper/vg_saswork--prd-lv_sas--saswork 3.1T 2.2T 861G 73% 
/saswork

Input: du -h /saswork | sort -rh | head -20
Output: 
569G/saswork/SAS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03/SAS_work9A0700007078_prdsasgridn03
```

**569G /saswork/SAS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03**
526G/saswork/SAS_work445F00002079_prdsasgridn01/SAS_work189900002079_prdsasgridn01
526G /saswork/SAS_work445F00002079_prdsasgridn01
165G/saswork/SAS_workBD3300007B7E_prdsasgridn04/SAS_work154B00007B7E_prdsasgridn04
165G/saswork/SAS_workBD3300007B7E_prdsasgridn04
134G/saswork/SAS_work36E800005097_prdsasgridn04/SAS_workA86000005097_prdsasgridn04
134G /saswork/SAS_work36E800005097_prdsasgridn04
110G /saswork/SAS_workB87B00002026_prdsasgridn01/SAS_workD37900002026_prdsasgridn01
110G /saswork/SAS_workB87B00002026_prdsasgridn01
105G/saswork/SAS_work55C800001BDA_prdsasgridn01/SAS_work849500001BDA_prdsasgridn01
105G /saswork/SAS_work55C800001BDA_prdsasgridn01
57G/saswork/SAS_work3FB700003AAF_prdsasgridn03/SAS_work826800003AAF_prdsasgridn03
57G /saswork/SAS_work3FB700003AAF_prdsasgridn03
55G/saswork/SAS_work8744000068D9_prdsasgridn01/SAS_work8CA9000068D9_prdsasgridn01
55G /saswork/SAS_work8744000068D9_prdsasgridn01
46G/saswork/SAS_work400B00002BFF_prdsasgridn02/SAS_work668100002BFF_prdsasgridn02
46G /saswork/SAS_work400B00002BFF_prdsasgridn02
40G/saswork/SAS_work67780000280E_prdsasgridn02/SAS_work91E90000280E_prdsasgridn02

```
Input: ls -la|  grep **SAS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03** NOTE: The 
foldername SAS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03 came from one of the results 
from the second command output. That's where I need to pull it from for each 
one.
Output: drwx------. 3 **g6753** ereapp 3864 Jul 12 12:25 
AS_work438800007078_prdsasgridn03
Note - bold in this line is the ID of the developer that I need.
```

Comment: post input and expected output, I'm not sure what you want from question.

Comment: Try this one, "du -h /workfld | sort -rh | head -20 | xargs ls -la"

Comment: @Buddika I never get a response from this it just hangs.

Comment: @rpt124 It hangs when there are tons of files, like when I do that on "/" it takes several minutes to produce an output.

Comment: @Buddika this is giving me different results that the command that gets me the top 20 folder names that are using the most /saswork disk space. So the output of the top 20 command is where I get each foldername to than run a command to check that folder for what developer ID that folder is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to see a list of the owner of the largest directories (in descending order). In other words:

1. You want to sort directories based on their size
2. Find the user ID of each of the top 20 largest directories.

If you want see the output in the `ls -l` format, then try this:

```
(du -sh ./*; ls -lh --color=no) | awk '{ if($1 == "total") {X = 1} else if (!X) {SIZES[$2] = $1} else { sub($5 "[ ]*", sprintf("%-7s ", SIZES["./" $9]), $0); print $0} }' | sort --key=5,5hr
```

**Sample output:**

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1017G   Jun 20 15:44 Raw_data_files
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  188G    May 12 11:34 Old_data
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8.8G    Jul 12 15:28 backups
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1.4G    Jun 29 15:32 randomized_sets
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  124M    May 22 10:41 archive_web.html.7z
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  113M    Jan 15 14:51 example1.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  113M    Apr 15 13:27 example3.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1.0M    Apr 15 09:17 sample_info.xlsx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1.0M    Apr 27 09:20 sample_info2.xlsx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1.0M    Jun 12 09:18 sample_run.R
```

As you can see, this gives you a sorted list (based on size) of all directories **and** files. But you are only interested in directories/folders and their size and user id. So if you add a simple pipe to all that (the command above) and use the `grep` command (i.e. add `| grep "^d" --color=never"` to the command above), you will then only get directories listed, and files will be no longer listed.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1017G   Jun 20 15:44 Raw_data_files
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  188G    May 12 11:34 Old_data
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8.8G    Jul 12 15:28 backups
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1.4G    Jun 29 15:32 randomized_sets
```

So in this case, the complete command will be as follows:

```
(du -sh ./*; ls -lh --color=no) | awk '{ if($1 == "total") {X = 1} else if (!X) {SIZES[$2] = $1} else { sub($5 "[ ]*", sprintf("%-7s ", SIZES["./" $9]), $0); print $0} }' | sort --key=5,5hr | grep "^d" --color=never"
```

All you have to do next is to only add `head -20` to command above to see only the top 20 largest directories.

**All credit** goes to Stack Overflow user [**Sebi**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639370/sebi). See this thread on SO for more information: [*Using ls to list directories and their total sizes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019116/using-ls-to-list-directories-and-their-total-sizes)

Comment: not real sure what you mean by/or how to "f you pipe all that into a simple grep command (i.e. | grep "^d" --color=never"), you will then only get directories listed:"

Comment: I just added the full command including `grep`.

Comment: Ok so yes I understand this however I need to take the folder name from the result of the second command and place it into this command so that I can get the developers ID of who uses that folder? So I am asking how do I take the results of the command of the largest folders in that directory and there output used in the third command so that I can get the developers IDs for each folder.

Comment: To Clarify here is the command I run to get the top 20 directories inside the /saswork directory. 'du -h /saswork | sort -rh | head -20'   That output I need to take each directory name from the top 5 and place that directory name inside this command to get the developer output 'ls -la|grep SAS_work18EE00003BA8_prdsasgridm01' The SAS_WORK..... is one of the directory names from the first command output.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the result of a command in a variable you just need to wrap the command between `` or $():

```
yourvar=`date +%Y`
```

or

```
yourvar=$(date +%Y)
```

yourvar will have the value of the current year (2018). You can also execute the result directly in your command:

```
ls -la|  grep `date +%Y`
```

or

```
ls -la|  grep $(date +%Y)
```

To achive what you want I would use a for loop:

```
for i in `du -h |sort -rh|awk '{print $2}'|sed "s/.\///g"`;do ls -la |grep $i|awk '{print $3 " " $9}';done
```

Bear in mind that the command is a rough example and it may need to be tweeked to avoid doubles (since if your directory has subdirectories you will have various outputs for the same parent).

Comment: When using either of these I get responses like: Invalid argument
grep: 167G: No such file or directory

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have used your example since it gives an unformated output that is useless for your needs (two fields per output line). My answer is to show how to keep a command result in a variable (which is what I thought you were asking) or use it inside other command. I'll modify my answer to make it usable.

Comment: To Clarify here is the command I run to get the top 20 directories inside the /saswork directory. 'du -h /saswork | sort -rh | head -20' That output I need to take each directory name from the top 5 and place that directory name inside this command to get the developer output 'ls -la|grep SAS_work18EE00003BA8_prdsasgridm01' The SAS_WORK..... is one of the directory names from the first command output.